# How to connect and authenticate on the STMP server

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-validation

I need to connect to the GMAIL SMTP server with email and password, without sending email and then receiving 200 OK.

I using the code PHPMailer:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "myuser@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("");
$mail->Subject = utf8_decode("My subject");
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("destination@gmail.com");

$mail->Body = template('emails/reset-password', compact('comentario'));

if ($mail->Send()) {
  $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
  $mail->ClearAttachments();
}
```

My script is sending email, I would just like to validate the authentication.

Comment: Have you done any research on this?

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer itself isn't much use for this as it's all about the sending. However, the SMTP class that's part of PHPMailer can do this just fine, and there is [a script provided with PHPMailer that does exactly as you ask](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp_check.phps). I'm not going to reproduce the script here as it just creates maintenance for me!

The script connects to an SMTP server, starts TLS, and authenticates, and that's all.

Comment: You have link?
Beacause my test with PHPMailer not work.

Comment: There’s a link in my answer?

Comment: I am not working with Laravel.
I am working with structured PHP, not object.

Comment: The link I gave you has nothing to do with Laravel. It’s a completely stand-alone script that uses PHPMailer’s SMTP class, which is what you asked for.